# Is there a command to stop further SQL commands to execute in MySQL Workbench scripts?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have tried to find an answer to how to stop the execution of SQL scripts in MySQL Workbench. It should be easy to find a solution (if it's possible)... but I haven't found anything.

In MySQL Workbench I execute a couple of SQL commands in sequence. But I would like to stop the script execution after a while. Here's an example of what I try to achieve:

```
SELECT "Hello";
STOP;             # What command can I use here to stop the execution?
SELECT "World";
```

I don't want the `SELECT "World"` to execute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **##** at start of the line for one line or **/* */** for mor lines like:

```
SELECT 1;

-- SELECT 1;
    
/*

SELECT 1;
SELECT 2;
SELECT 3;

*/

SELECT 99;
```

see manual: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/comment-syntax/

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I need. I have a script that resets some testdata. I want to have some one-line-scripts that may be used. Therefore I need a STOP statement of some sort to prevent these one-liners to execute automatically after my testdata script.

Comment: @Gowire you  can use in MySQL Workbench 6.3 
**Execute (All or Selection) -> Ctrl + Shift + Enter** or **Execute Current Statement -> Ctrl + Enter**

Comment: @Gowire - i am not using workbench, but in sequel pro i have testet. I comment all queries with one /* */ . then 1 mark a line and can execute it

Answer (score 0):

`STOP;` actually works, exactly as you show it.

Here's a screenshot. Notice only 'Hello' has been output.

[image]

Any statement that causes an error will stop execution.

Comment: That's correct... if and only if you have enabled the option "Stop Script Execution on Errors" (found in menu **Query -> Stop Script Execution on Errors**... I will use this option. I was hoping for a real command that stopped the script more gracefully :)